# JUnit test case not returning proper values when used when then return condition

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit5

Here is the code I am using. 
The test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class XTest{

        @Mock 
        XRepository xRepository ;

        @Mock
        XServiceImpl xServiceImpl ;

        X x = new X();

        XC xC= new XC();
        List<X> lX= new ArrayList<X>();

        @BeforeEach
        void createProcedure(){
            x.setId((long)1);
            x.setDescription("First one");
            x.setValue("10");
            xC.setCode("X");
            x.setCategory(xC);

            lX.add(x);
        }       

        @Test
        void testGetXByCode() {
            Mockito.when(xRepository.findByCode(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(lX);
            List<X> xL= xServiceImpl.getProcedureByCode("X");
            System.out.println(lX.size());
            assertEquals(1,xL.size());
            assertNotEquals("Y", xL.get(0).getCategory().getCode() );
        }
}
```

My service implementation class:

```
@Service
public class XServiceImpl implements XService {

    private final XRepository xRepository;

    @Autowired
    public XServiceImpl(XRepository xRepository) {
        this.xRepository = xRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<X> getXByCode(String code) {
        List<X> x= new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            x= xRepository.findByCode(code);
            if (!x.isEmpty()) {
                return x;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And my repository code is as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface XRepository extends JpaRepository<X, Long>{

    public Optional<X> findById(Long id);

}
```

Both the test cases seem to be failing. Can anyone help me out with this?
The actual size of the list is 1 which is being printed. But when then return doesn't seem to be returning the same one.

Answer (score 0):

@Mock creates mock. You should annotate XServiceImpl with @InjectMocks so that creates an instance of the class and injects the mocks that are created with the @Mock annotations (such as XRepository).

```
@InjectMocks
XServiceImpl xServiceImpl;
```

Comment: can you tell me the location, where you are getting the nullpointer?